# I have a problem with this scrapy script to export data from a site

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping, scrapy-shell

I have a problem with this scrapy script to export data from a site. It used to work now when I launch it it gives me an error that I don't understand

```js
2022-03-02 15:52:10 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://sofifa.com/player/158023?units=mks/> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 120, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/utils/python.py", line 353, in __next__
    return next(self.data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 342, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 40, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 56, in _evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/Users/trivius86/Documents/fifa-stats-crawler-master/fifa_crawler/fifa_parser/spiders/players_stats.py", line 89, in parse
    age, month, day, year, height, weight = player_info[0].split()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your are getting `None` type values from `player_info` under some instances, and so you cannot index a `None` value. Therefore, you're getting thrown the following error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

To proceed, you might want to instantiate your code within an `if-statement`, something like:

```
if player_info != None:
    age, month, day, year, height, weight = player_info[0].split()
else:
    pass
```